# Joomla 301 Redirect Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I'm working on a Joomla 3.2.0 site for a client and for some reason the 301 Redirects in the .htaccess aren't working.  I've tried a number of different solutions that I've found on here and elsewhere.

I need to redirect the old URLs to fit the setup of the new site, additionally so that links from search engines work correctly and customers that try to use old URLs can still get where they're trying to go.

I'm trying to redirect http://www.mysite.com/client-login/ to http://www.mysite.com/index.php/2013-12-30-04-44-07/dhs-login

I've tried the following:

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /client-login/ http://www.mysite.com/index.php/2013-12-30-04-44-07/dhs-login
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/client-login/$ "http://www.mysite.index.php" [R=301,L]
```

I've also tried the redirect system built into Joomla with no luck...

I would appreciate some help if anyone has an idea how to fix this

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other rules in the htaccess file that works? Maybe the site does not have htaccess enabled. If you have access to the Apache config file check that you have `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride None` in your directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not writing correctly your RewriteRule, try without qoutation marks and write your base:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^client-login/$ /2013-12-30-04-44-07/dhs-login [R=301,L]
```

Check regular expresions, you may use http://regexpal.com for that.

Anyway, if you have to redirect ALL your web traffic, deppending of your web structure maybe is better if you guide all the traffic to a specific PHP controller which redirect with 301 header the traffic according to several rules you specify. In occasions is easier than rewrite directly in the .htaccess

Comment: thanks for your reply... however it still doesn't seem to be working. I tried some variations for the code but still had no luck. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: When you write http://www.mysite.com/client-login/, where does it go? And have you write your rewrite rule before the main Joomla redirect?

Comment: I had to enable URL rewriting in the global configuration and then your suggestion worked. Thanks again!